# find the minimum value of this integral when $1>t>0$, $f(t)=\int\limits_0^1 x |e^{-x^2} - t|\ \mathrm{d}x = ?$

Tags: integration, optimization

Is there someone who can show me How do i find  the minimum value of this integral   when $1>t>0$,  \begin{align*}f(t)=\int\limits_0^1 x |e^{-x^2} - t|\ \mathrm{d}x &= \end{align*}

Note : I accrossed it in my texbook ,he put dircetly the result :$\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$ , but i don't know how ?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is obvious that the minimum is when $1>t>0$, (since $e^{-x^2}<1$ on the interval of integration). \begin{align*}f(t)=\int\limits_0^1 x |e^{-x^2} - t|\ \mathrm{d}x &= \int\limits_0^{\alpha}   x(e^{-x^2}-t)\ \mathrm{d}x + \int\limits_{\alpha}^1   x(t-e^{-x^2})\ \mathrm{d}x .\end{align*} Where: $\alpha =\sqrt{-\ln t}$. Now you have two ways for doing it, you may differentiate directly the RHS (differentiation under the integral sign) or just calculate it in terms of $t$ to get : $f(t)=\frac{-e t+2 e t \ln(t)+e+1}{2 e}$, Differentiate to get that $f$ attains it minimum at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$.
Therefore, the requested minimum value is : $f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\right)= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2e} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} \approx0.0774091$

Comment: thank you for this answer, it's helpful answer